# Get the last value after spliting a string with hyphen in jquery?

Tags: jquery

Hi all i will have a string separated with hyphens in and i want to get the lastindex of the string and replace it with new value

```
   var str1="New-New_Folder"; //Replace New_Folder with Folder so that the str becomes
   var newstr1="New-Folder";


   var str2="New-New_Folder-New_Folder"; //Replace the last New_Folder with Sub_Folder so that the str becomes
   var newstr2="New-New_Folder-Sub_Folder";
```

can any one help me here?

Comment: I've read this twice, now, and I'm still unsure what you're asking. What string do you want to replace? What do you want to replace it *with*?

Answer (score 1):

You can use split then get the last index with the length minus one:

```
var string = "some-hyphen-string";
var parts = string.split("-");
var lastPart = parts[parts.length - 1]; //lastPart is now the final index string split
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ACfRU/

Answer (score 0):

I have to admit this is very unclear, but maybe with tymeJV's answer and mine you can come up with a solution that fits your needs.

```
var str1="New-New_Folder";
var newstr2 = replaceLast(str1, "Sub_Folder");

alert(newstr2);

function replaceLast(strWhat, strWith) {
    strWhat = strWhat.split("-");
    strWhat[strWhat.length - 1] = strWith;
    strWhat = strWhat.join("-");
    return strWhat;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FF96g/

Answer (score 0):

Using String functions:

```
var str1 = "New-New_Folder";
var newstr1 = str1.substring(0, str1.lastIndexOf("-")+1) + "Folder";
```